# Error: No xenial release for kernel-ppa

Tags: kernel, software-sources

Full error:

```
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Normal `sources.list`:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

I see that the kernel-ppa has [no xenial dist folder](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu/dists/). How can I fix this error or deactivate the from throwing an error over the lack of xenial folder?

Comment: If you're interested in kernels from future releases, you may want this PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa`. It has kernels usable in Xenial. For example, the Yakkety kernel can be installed with `sudo apt update; sudo apt install linux-image-generic-lts-yakkety`.

Answer (score 1):

[Removing](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/49899) the PPA removed the error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
```